# How to perform Spatial derivative calculation?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, derivative, corners, harris

I'm trying to solve the following question about "Harris Corner Detection".

Consider the following image:

[image]

As the first step of the "Harris Corner Detection", we should compute the derivatives using the differentiation kernels shown above. No normalization (division by 2) is needed.

What I did:
$$
I_{x}=\frac{\partial I(x,y)}{\partial x}=I(x+1,y)-I(x-1,y)=\begin{bmatrix}4 & 9 & 12\\
8 & 11 & 14\\
10 & 15 & 16
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 4\\
0 & 5 & 7\\
4 & 9 & 12
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4 & 8 & 8\\
8 & 6 & 7\\
6 & 6 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But the solution should be ([source](https://wp.kntu.ac.ir/nasihatkon/teaching/cvug/s2018/cv-undergrad-final-Spring2018-key.pdf)):

[image]

I'm a bit confused about spatial derivative calculation. I took the formula from [here](https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*XRHNrILWvKug8ICzwyK5xQ.png). What am I missing?

I quite don't get how to calculate:
$$
M=\sum_{x,y}w(x,y)\begin{bmatrix}I_{x}^{2} & I_{x}I_{y}\\
I_{x}I_{y} & I_{y}^{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm also a bit confused about terminology. Is $I_x$ actually that matrix or is it some value? function?

Is it possible to show how can I calculate $M$ using the following formula I provided above?

Comment: Your $I_x$ is actually moving in the $y$ axis (vertical axis) not the $x$ axis (horizontal axis). That will make the answer match the blue figures in the image.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do instead to calculate $I_x$:

$$
\begin{align}
I_{x}(x,y)&=\frac{\partial I(x,y)}{\partial x}\\
&=I(x+1,y)-I(x-1,y)\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}5& 7 & 11\\
9 & 12 & 16\\
11 & 14 & 16
\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 5\\
1 & 4 & 9\\
3 & 8 & 11
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix} \bf\color{blue} 4 & \bf\color{blue}7 & \bf\color{blue}6\\
\bf\color{blue}8 & \bf\color{blue}8 & \bf\color{blue}7\\
\bf\color{blue}8 & \bf\color{blue}6 & \bf\color{blue}5
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
which matches the expected output.

Checking on [your source](https://wp.kntu.ac.ir/nasihatkon/teaching/cvug/s2018/cv-undergrad-final-Spring2018-key.pdf), it seems that $M$ is mis-transcribed:

[image: Harris corner detector equation]

Here, the $W$ is a *window* into the image, not a weighting as is written in the equation for $M$ in the original post.  This just means that $x$ and $y$ are varied to capture the window and the sum of the four different items is computed.

To calculate this $H$, all you need is the $I_x$ above and the equivalent in the $y$ direction:
$$
\begin{align}
I_{y}(x,y)&=\frac{\partial I(x,y)}{\partial y}\\
&=I(x,y+1)-I(x,y+1)\\
\end{align}
$$